# Setting margins exactly

Tags: margins, geometry

My thesis formatting requires 1.5-inch margin on the left side and a 1-inch margin on the three remaining sides. Since all pages must be printed on one side of the page, I used the following:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

some text here

\end{document}
```

But something is wrong. On the even pages the left margin is little smaller than 1.5 inch. And on the odd pages the right margin is less than 1 inch. I couldn't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: Why are you using the option `oneside` in the `documentclass`?

Thanks for the snippet, but that is not a full MWE. Read carefully the comment above this one. And read the links please.

Comment: I am not an experienced user, I found that use in a blog.

Comment: Do you mean that you have not idea how to use `LaTeX`?

Comment: I have some familiarity but I am not an expert. I always used article class but now I need chapters so I opted for the book class. I had never measured margins by hand, I got curious and see that they are actually wrong.

Comment: Make sure that the pdf-viewer (and your printer) doesn't scale down the page during printing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good reminder -- I just discovered I had spent hours trying to fix LaTeX margin settings that were actually the result of the printer.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, A4 papersize is assume, but I specified it directly. The `showframe` option to the `geometry` package shows the margins

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Print this document, use a ruler and measure the margins with it.

The screen shot shows the frame, the thick black border is from the window background, it has nothing to do with the `*.pdf` output.

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason for a4paper? It will be printed on letter-size.

Comment: @lobeam: Did you mention `letter` size at all? ;-)

Comment: No, but isn't letter-size default?

Comment: Depends on the settings of TL at installation -- In Germany with don't use `lettersize`. You can change it, of course, to `lettersize`

Comment: @lobeam The default size in the stanrdard classes such as `article` or `book` is in fact `lettersize`. If you don't specify in the options of the class, your document will be printed in letter size sheets.

Comment: In North America we still use `lettersize`, at least in the US and Mexico, perhaps in Canada also. I don't know why @lobeam uses it.

Comment: @lobeam: I have to use `a4paper` here, otherwise I could not print it ;-)

Comment: I am in the US, I use lettersize

Comment: OK with this code (excluding a4paper), left-margin is little greater than 1.5inch and right-margin is little smaller than 1inch. It is weird.

Comment: @lobeam: I changed it to `lettersize`, I can't print it (no paper available in that format, at this time (7 o'clock in the morning), but it works definitely with `a4paper` (Printed a test)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, a leaner solution would be:

```
\usepackage{fullpage}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-.5in}
```

`fullpage` sets all margins to 1in and the \pagestyle to `plain` by default, so you only have to increase the \oddsidemargin by .5 in and compensate the displacement by decreasing \textwidth by the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext} %creates a dummy for a document.
\usepackage{layout} % shows you the layout composition of the pages.
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\Blinddocument % Creates a large document that shows you a whole description of the layout of a document such as book.
%\blinddocument % The same like the first but with a shorter document, such as article.

\layout % This show you a diagram with all the variables and values that use the documentclass you're using.

\end{document}
```

Is almost the same like in the answer of Christian, but I use the macro `\Blinddocument` for create a full dummy that shows you a better and more complete layout. I also added the package `layout` that shows you see a diagram that can be useful for edit the dimensions of the page, although `geometry` does it very easy.